# break word so that it fits screen

Tags: html, css

On this site: `http://www.faadinkroptilbage.dk` I need the section that says: `Sidste nyt` (which is the section on top) to fit the screen, when the screen gets smaller. Right now it is unreadable when the screen gets small enough.

Many solutions suggest doing something like:

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

This doesn't help in my case, I'm not sure why. I am not so experienced with css.
I also tried adding: `word-wrap: break-word;` but with no luck.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: you want like this? hello world how... ? three dots when screen size smaller?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your issue is caused by the explicit `width: 675px;` you have on `#mtphr-dnt-326`. No need for break word etc, just get rid of that width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is caused by the explicit `width: 675px;` you have on `#mtphr-dnt-326`. No need for break word etc, just get rid of that width

Answer (score 1):

You have an inline style width of 675px in your div with the id of "mtphr-dnt-326". Removing this width will fix your issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this to CSS file

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
   #mtphr-dnt-326{max-width:100%;}
}
```